# Intergrate 3D model in Web

Tags: plugins, three.js, 3d, webgl, webvr

I am trying to integrate 3d model on the web. I don't want to upload my model to any third party site and embed the iframe given by third-party site like Modelo.

I did try on some on the step on internet but couldn't do it in any professional manner .

I don't know if i am missing anything so that problem may sound easy .

**Any suggestion please !! .**

I am trying my hand on three.js though i am very new to three.js .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a nice challenge, good luck with that...

Comment: This is a statement and not a question.

Comment: @brakebein i have edited question ... hope u will find it easy to understand now

Answer (score 1):

You can store and serve the models yourself, for example, from an [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket, and then download and render them on your own webpage using JavaScript and three.js.

Comment: is this best way for now ?? i am learning three.js for this from last two day . I don't know if this is the best way to build something beautiful smartly ... thanks for ur answer .

Comment: It's the way it's typically done. Three.js provides a lot of great examples. Here's one that demonstrates exactly what you're asking for: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obj#webgl_loader_obj. It loads and renders an OBJ file. No special hosting or embedding needed.